# How to add settings for Android in the message

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I have a code that prepares and sends a notification to a mobile application

```
// Create the notification
const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: "Title",
        body: "Body",
    },
};

// Options
const options = {
    contentAvailable: true,
    priority: 'high'
};

admin
    .messaging()
    .sendToDevice(tokenSnapshot, payload, options)
    .then(response => {
        console.warn(">> Notification sent successfully: ", response);
        return response;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.warn(">> Notification sent failed: ", error);
    });
```

I would like to add here information such as:

- `priority: 'max'`
- `visibility: 'public'`

These are features supported in Android

It is mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.AndroidNotification#optional-visibility) that it exists.

But there is nothing mentioned how to use it

Can anyone give advice?

*The purpose of this is to display Notifications on your phone when it is in the background*

Comment: I suggest using the "send feedback" button at the top right of the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message), and also filing an issue on the [Firebase Admin GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node) to get the attention of the people who maintain this software.